# create nsbutton manually - call function

Tags: swift, macos, nsbutton

This question probably is trivial but I am searching for hours now and just dont find the fitting link.

I am programming a board game with many fields like a chess board. I managed to create all fields as buttons with for ... in and code like this:

```
let feld = NSButton()
feld.frame = CGRect(x: 1300+30*h, y: 20, width: 22, height: 22)
feld.image = NSImage(named: NSImage.Name("Mulleimer"))
arrayOfButtons.append(feld)
```

When a button is pressed I want to start a function. How to do this!?
I only found code for C++ and Ios but not for Swift Macos.
For example this one was given for Ios but I dont know how to change it to MacOS:

```
feld.Target(self, action: #selector(ButtonReiheDeaktivieren), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add target and action like this:

```
fled.target = self
fled.action = #selector(ButtonTest)
```

Comment: I did this but it doesnt start the function. I receive the yellow mistake message:
"String literal is not a valid Objective-C selector"

Comment: It worked now!
feld.action = #selector(ViewController.ButtonTest)

Comment: My bad. Updated the answer. Please accept the answer if you found it useful.

Comment: Thanks. I voted the answer "useful". (if there is another way to accept an answer please tell me.)

Comment: Please follow the instructions in this link to accept the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: I had programmatically created an NSTextView and an NSButton, placing them in the same parent NSView. I set the action of the button, but not the target. Of course the action was not called when clicking the button, however, if I clicked in the NSTextField, thereafter, the NSButton action would be called. Setting the NSButton target fixed that.